# How to copy all bytes of a phone (formatted or not, 64GB/64B) into a computer hard drive?

Tags: data-recovery, iphone

For example, I have an iPhone (64GB) with data erased through factory reset. The deleted data is usually not lost, just differently encrypted (at least before IOS 13). A typical way to recover the deleted data is to scan the whole iPhone and find the fragments of deleted (encrypted) data, and then decipher the data.

Using the iPhone again will start to overwrite those encrypted data.

Since I need to use the phone for other uses right now, and I don't have time to run a deep scan at now, I need to make a copy of the iphone's entire hard drive, to save a copy of the encrypted data.

This cannot be completed by just backing up the phone. This is because the usually back-up methods only copies the formatted data, which is around 5GB/64GB.

I want to "back-up" the entire 64GB of binary data into my computer. Does professionals have a way to do this in theory?

Comment: Id be surprised if this is meaningfully doable with the kind of TPM built into most phones. (ie even if you do manage to get a dump of the data, it will remain forever encrypted as the header likely no longer exists, so there is no way to decrypt it)

Comment: How did you erase the data on that phone?

Comment: @nohillside Reset to factory settings

Answer (score 5):

No, that's not a typical way to recover lost data on iPhones. In almost every instance, your old data is either UNMAP'ed (TRIM'ed) or it was encrypted and now the encryption key is gone. So a copy of the iPhones entire drive won't do you any good, and you won't be able to recover your lost data that way.

You're talking about recovering data from the non-formatted part of the drive - that doesn't really make sense in this scenario. There's nothing to be gained there.

At the level where you're asking this question, no, there's no practical way for you to do this.

For professionals there are ways to copy the drive. Those professionals still won't be able to recover your lost data from such a copy alone.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135135/discussion-on-answer-by-jksoegaard-how-to-copy-all-bytes-of-a-phone-formatted-o).